# Slow first query on MYSQL with Java web app +tomcat 8 + C3p0

Tags: mysql, hibernate, c3p0

I have a vps on Digital Ocean with Ubuntu 14.0.4, ssd 40GB and 2GB of RAM. There I installed LAMP, Apache Tomcat 8, and openjdk version "1.8.0_72-internal".

Everything seems to work well, exeto by the fact that the first query after some idle time on the server takes longer than expected. After that the query's are very fast.

I read somewhere that this has to do with the C3P0 configuration. And as my java web app uses hibernate and C3P0, here's the settings I currently use.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
```

Remembering that this is the first time I have to deal with the installation and configuration of a vps.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?